# Clean DataFrame fields in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in Python using Pandas obtained importing a .csv file. Now, the DataFrame has several columns, where some columns have int or string data, while other columns have Json data.
Ex:

```
         AA         A                            B  \
        40.0     90.0        {"0": 5.5815269769616, "1": 5.7224734728583, "...
```

**I have multiple rows but for sake of simplicity I just past on of it.**

Now, I would erase the braces and all the stuff within 'B' between quote, and also, having the entries as arrays or list.
Basically, this should be the result:

```
        AA         A                            B  \
        40.0     90.0         [5.5815269769616,5.7224734728583,3.4456]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use `df.B.apply(some_function)`, where `some_function` parses the json string and gives you your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` function to `B` column:

```
import json
df.B = df.B.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).values())
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
This is the result

Comment: @user7311536 This means values in `B` column are not `dict`s but `str`s. But in your question they appear as `dict`s.

Comment: I'm sorry @Carles but I wrote String Data.

Comment: Congrats, genius